# Cursor returning row 1 multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to get the contents of my database to appear in a `ListView`.  There is something wrong (obviously) and it is returning row #1 in the database multiple times.

For instance, if there are 2 row, it returns row #1 2 times.. if I add another record, it returns row #1 3 times.

Here is my **history.java**

```
...
MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

Cursor cursor = db.getAllLogs();
Log.d("history.java", "finished Cursor cursor = db.getAllLogs();");
GasCursorAdapter adapter = new GasCursorAdapter(this, cursor, 0);
Log.d("history.java", "GasCursorAdapter adapter = new GasCursorAdapter(this, cursor, 0);");
listContent.setAdapter(adapter);
Log.d("history.java", "setAdapter(adapter);");
```

and here is my **MySQLiteHelper.java**

```
...
public Cursor getAllLogs() {    
    List<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_GASLOG;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

I'm guessing it's something I need to do in `getAllLogs()`... however I can't quite pinpoint it.  I've tried to use `cursor.moveToFirst()` and `moveToNext` but that seems to yield the same results... It seems to know there are multiple records but just returns the first one that many times!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT (Additional Information)
**newRecord.java**

```
public class newRecord extends Activity {

String fill;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_record);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Roboto-Light.ttf");


    final MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

    final EditText pricePerGallon = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pricePerGallon);
    final EditText gallons = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gallons);
    final EditText odometer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.odometer);
    final EditText today = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
    final EditText comments = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comments);
    final CheckBox notCompleteFill = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.completeFill);
    TextView save = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.save);
    TextView reset = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    pricePerGallon.setTypeface(tf);
    gallons.setTypeface(tf);
    odometer.setTypeface(tf);
    today.setTypeface(tf);
    comments.setTypeface(tf);
    notCompleteFill.setTypeface(tf);
    save.setTypeface(tf);
    reset.setTypeface(tf);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    today.setText( sdf.format(new Date()));

    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            String pricePerGallonString = pricePerGallon.getText().toString();
            final double pricePerGallonInt = Double.parseDouble(pricePerGallonString);
            String gallonsString = gallons.getText().toString();
            final double gallonsInt = Double.parseDouble(gallonsString);
            String odometerString = odometer.getText().toString();
            final double odometerInt = Double.parseDouble(odometerString);
            String todayString = today.getText().toString();
            String notCompleteFillString = notCompleteFill.getText().toString();
            String commentsString = comments.getText().toString();

            db.addGasLog(new gasLog(pricePerGallonInt, gallonsInt, odometerInt, todayString, fill, commentsString));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(newRecord.this, history.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

**MySQLiteHelper.java**

```
public void addGasLog(gasLog gasLog){
        // for logging
        Log.d("addGasLog", gasLog.toString());

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_PRICE_PER_GALLON, gasLog.getPricePerGallon()); // get price
        values.put(KEY_GALLONS, gasLog.getGallons()); // get gallons
        values.put(KEY_ODOMETER, gasLog.getOdometer()); // get odometer
        values.put(KEY_DATE, gasLog.getDate()); // get date
        values.put(KEY_FILLED_OR_NOT, gasLog.getFilledOrNot()); // get filledOrNot
        values.put(KEY_COMMENTS, gasLog.getComments()); // get comments

        // 3. insert
        db.insert(TABLE_GASLOG, //table
                null, //nullColumnHack
                values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values =

        // 4. Close
        db.close();
    }
```

EDIT2
**GasCursorAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GasCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


    //private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;

    public GasCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags){
        super(context, c, flags);
        //mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Log.d("inGasCursorAdapter", "GasCursorAdapter");
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_background, parent, false);
        Log.d("inGasCursorAdapter", "newView");
        return retView;
        //return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_background,  parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor){
        /*
         * cardDate
         * cardGallons
         * cardPrice
         * cardMPG
         */

        TextView cardDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardDate);
        int date = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_DATE);
        cardDate.setText(Integer.toString(date));

        TextView cardGallons = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardGallons);
        int gallons = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_GALLONS);
        cardGallons.setText(Integer.toString(gallons) + "gal");

        TextView cardPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardPrice);
        int price = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_PRICE_PER_GALLON);
        cardPrice.setText("$" + Integer.toString(price));

        TextView cardMPG = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardMPG);
        int MPG = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteHelper.KEY_ODOMETER);
        cardMPG.setText(Integer.toString(MPG));

        TextView cardDelete = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardDelete);
        cardDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your insert method also. Your select query is ok, so it must be the data you actually insert.

Comment: Can you post the code for GasCursorAdapter?

Comment: Insert looks ok as well - try to add some print statements to the `onClick` method of your `Button` and add some logging to your `addGas` method, so see if the correct data is actually inserted at that point.

Comment: I have added GasCursorAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Does your table have a column named _id?  If not you might need to select the individual columns (which you should do anyway instead of select *) and alias your key primary key to be _id.

Comment: Yes the table has a column called _id

Comment: Ted why do you suggest him to name all columns instead of just using `*`?

Comment: It's performance/maintenance thing.  Since "select *" gets you all columns, that means you might be pulling in data for other columns that you don't need, just to discard it.  Even if the table doesn't have extra columns today, it might later on which turns it into a maintenance issue.

Comment: He said he wanted to get all rows and columns, so to me it sounds like one of those performance optimisation that you shouldn't really do, unless there is a performance issue. It would be more commendable to use a `LIMIT` clause when pulling data if you'd really wanted to performance optimise something.

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about all rows and columns, just "the contents of my database".  Using LIMIT has nothing to do with columns.  Not using select * is a best practice, not a performance optimization.

Comment: It's better to limit the amount of rows than the amount of columns - especially when there's only 5-6 columns. Using `LIMIT` with say 10-20 rows instead of just pulling everything from the database, even though you specify the columnnames, would be a lot better. And also a `ListView` usually holds around 10 rows at any given time.
But I'll leave it to you... `*` doesn't do any "bad" things for OP - imho it's a wasted advice...

Comment: "especially when there's only 5-6 columns".  That's exactly why this is a maintenance issue.  There might not be 5-6 column next year, and then you have to go back to all the different places using select * and fix them.  The code clearly shows he only wants specific columns, and also implies (from the name method getAllLogs) he wants all the rows.  So using LIMIT is actually bad advice because it changes the requirement. Not using select * is good advice because it accomplishes the same thing with better design.  Less code != better.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46466/discussion-between-ted-bigham-and-darwind)